# Google Fusion Table Change individual Marker Type

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have a simple question for someone who is familiar with Google Fusion Tables. Basically I want a user to be able to change a marker style on the map by indirectly altering the numerical column that corresponds to the markerstyle type.

Specifically, I currently have a Fusion Table with approximately 7000 addresses and the corresponding map. I am wondering if there is anyway FROM THE MAP to change the marker type. Here is how I currently have it configured: I have a column in the fusion table that divides the marker types into 'buckets' that plot different marker types. Right now they are all red circles, and as i visit each location I want to individually change the marker type (so in the table I would change the 1 (which corresponds to red) to a 3 (which corresponds to green)) so that I know which houses I visited. But it isnt feasible for me to scroll down the fusion table of 7000 points and change the 1 to 3, so Im wondering if theres anyway I can change it on the map directly EITHER FROM A MAP ON A WEBPAGE OR ON THE FUSION TABLE MAP INSIDE GOOGLE.

Thank you in advance,
David

Comment: is there any column with unique values in the table(except rowid)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fusion table derived map on a page, you could add a button to an info window that updates a value in a the fusion table - so you could change the value from 1 to 3.  Take it a bit further you could add a listener to the click on the map marker itself and change the value.

Updating a value (especially if you are an owner of the table) is straightforward (https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#updateRow or https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference#updateRow) and is basically a fairly standard form of sql manipulation using HTTP to invoke the request.

```
UPDATE <table_id>
SET <column_name> = <value> {, <column_name> = <value> }*
WHERE ROWID = <row_id>
```

Adding a listener to a marker to pup up an info window with an updating button is also straightforward:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

```
// This example displays a marker at the center of Australia.
// When the user clicks the marker, an info window opens.

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      'button that call some ajax to fire off a column update' +
      '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```